# JDK 1.8 Garbage collector G1 algorithm for classes compiled with JDK 1.7 version

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-8, heap-memory

I have many services in distributed application and all are running with JKD 1.7 (update 45) version. Out of these services, I have some memory intensive services with a heap of 4 GB RAM using CMS GC algorithm. I have found that existing algorithms including CMS are not effective for young gen intensive applications. The performance of these services is degrading with spike in messaging activity at random intervals.

I have read a lot of good things about JDK 1.8 [G1 algorithm](http://www.infoq.com/articles/G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All). But I can't upgrade all services to JDK 1.8 due to constraints on some of third party technologies, which are not ready for JDK 1.8 yet.

**Is it possible to just upgrade run time to JDK 1.8 version in some services + configure G1 algorithm for GC BUT still use java classes, compiled with JDK 1.7 version 45?**

Note: I have earlier upgrade JDK 1.7 run time in services with JDK 1.6 compiled classes. But this time, I have to play with GC algorithm and not sure how it behaves with JDK 1.7 compiled classes.If any one of you have already done, share your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The garbage collector and its algorithms live in the JVM. They don't care which version you used to compile the classes.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. One small doubt : Can I use new JVM options (perm gen removal etc.) with 1.8 version?. I think answer is YES from your answer but  had little doubt in mind. Just want to cross check once.

Comment: Of course. Again, the JVM doesn't treat your classes differently depending on which version they were compiled with (except that lower version JVMs don't support higher version classes, unless explicitly compiled for a lower version).